# Mvc customize routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I just want to customize routes in asp.net mvc ,
This is a blog website and I want to access controller methods using

> wwww.sitename.com/blog/{blogtitle}
>
> www.sitename.com/blog/{action}

**Blog Controller**

```
 public class BlogController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult Index(string title)
    {
        return View();
    }



        [Route("post-blog")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Blog blog,HttpPostedFileBase blogimage)
    {

        //some coe

    }
    [Route("post-blog")]
    public ActionResult Post()

    {

        if (Request.Cookies["userInfo"]==null)
        {
            return Redirect("/login");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

}

**Here is route Config**

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        //routes.Canonicalize().Www();
        routes.Canonicalize().Lowercase();




        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "freelogomaker", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


  }
```

But I am unable to hit action name "Index" using www.site.com/blog/titlename
But I can access "post-blog" using www.site.com/blog/post-blog

Please help me I am beginner in asp.net mvc routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your parameter to the route attribute within {} brackets to indicate that it should be read from the URL, and not from something else (such as POST body, dependency injections, etc)

```
[Route("{title}")]
public ActionResult Index(string title)
{
    return View();
}
```

I also like to add the RoutePrefix attribute to the controller to make it a bit clearer.

```
[RoutePrefix("blog")]
public class BlogController : Controller
```